# APLAY is not streaming the audio into speaker

Tags: alsa

Whenever I issue below command

"aplay 89400_Text1.wav -D sysdefault:CARD=0"

I could see the output as follows

Playing WAVE '89400_Text1.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 22050 Hz, Mono

But nothing is heard on speaker, could anyone help me to identify what might be the problem here.
Before issuing the aplay command noise was continuously heard from the speaker the same is observed after the aplay command.
I was expecting the audio to be played when I used the  aplay command.

Thank you.

Comment: Try and modify and make a new code which takes aplay libraries, and throws a fixed random integers in the buffer at pcm_write which will playback at the speaker. If this works, your speaker is fine, and some voice amplitude or hwparams needs to be changed.